# react native apk build fail when using react-native-razorpay

Tags: react-native, build, aapt

I'm trying to build an signed apk for my react-native code. I've used react-native-razorpay library for payment integration purpose. 
On running `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease` in my project root directory I got stuck on following error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-razorpay:verifyReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
102 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 100 up-to-date
```

While running `./gradlew assembleRelease --info` i get following in the last few lines-

```
....
....

Successfully started process 'command '/Users/clove/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt''
/Users/clove/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar/37abea56216e7a3ad9a6c076b6dd1a92/res/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3:5-157: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

/Users/clove/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar/37abea56216e7a3ad9a6c076b6dd1a92/res/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4:5-135: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

/Users/clove/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar/37abea56216e7a3ad9a6c076b6dd1a92/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.


> Task :react-native-razorpay:verifyReleaseResources FAILED
Putting task artifact state for task ':react-native-razorpay:verifyReleaseResources' into context took 0.0 secs.
Up-to-date check for task ':react-native-razorpay:verifyReleaseResources' took 0.0 secs. It is not up-to-date because:
  Task has failed previously.
All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':react-native-razorpay:verifyReleaseResources'.
Unable do incremental execution: full task run
QueuedCruncher is using /Users/clove/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt

Shutdown finished in 0ms

:react-native-razorpay:verifyReleaseResources (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 18,5,main]) completed. Took 0.402 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-razorpay:verifyReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 16s
102 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 93 up-to-date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Turned out that the problem was due to configuration mismatch. the gradle version I was using was above 3, which requires the android sdk version 25 or above. Whereas react-native-razorpay was shipped with sdk version 23. So I changed those settings in node_modules and the build completed successfully.